# Printing Out All Inputs

Tags: java, while-loop, java.util.scanner

I just want this program to print all the inputs in the second to the last line of the output. Please help me how to fix it.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array = new int[10];
        int sum = 0;
        int i = 0;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (sum <= 5 && i < array.length) {
            System.out.print("Enter the " + (i + 1) + "th number: ");


            array[i] = input.nextInt();
            sum += array[i];
            i++;

        }
        System.out.print("Your digits are: ");
        System.out.print(array[i] + " ");
        System.out.println("\nsum is " + sum);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only printing out the array at element i one time because it is not in a loop.

If you want to print out every element in the array you can use an enhanced for loop like this.

```
for(int x : array){
  System.out.print(x + " ");
}
```

This should loop through each element in the array giving the value to x and print it out.

OR

You can make a loop that only prints out the digits that have been entered in the array like this.

```
      int x = 0;
      for(; x < i; x++){
        System.out.print(array[x] + " ");
       }
```

Hopefully this is what you want. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you so much sir ))